# How to handle the Failed to load Clerk error

Tags: next.js, clerk

Clerk throws an error to the user when it is not able to refresh the access token. This mostly happens when the user is offline. But I do not want this because it kinda ruins the user experience, which in this case, the user might think that the website is broken. I want to handle the error myself and throw a nice error if it is necessary. How do I do this in next js. Here is what I have been trying to do but it is not working:

```
import { ClerkProvider } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Header from "../components/header/header";
import Footer from "../components/footer/footer";
import "../styles/globals.css";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleTokenRefreshError = (error) => {
    if (error.message === "Failed to load Clerk") {
      console.error("Token refresh failed");
    }
  };

  return (
    <ClerkProvider navigate={(to) => router.push(to)} onTokenRefreshError={handleTokenRefreshError}>
      <Header />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <Footer />
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}
```

I know clerk has the means to solve this error but there is just so little documentation to this matter. Any help will be appreciated.